# Empty custom row being inserted by recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have a custom Dialog layout for taking user input in the form of name and number and add it to the ArrayList being used by a recycler Adapter. An if else validation is also put in place to ensure that if user doesn't input anything a new row will not be added but the problem is it does. The code is as follows-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ContactModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ContactRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton btnOpenDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        btnOpenDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDialog);

        btnOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_contact_dialog_layout);

                EditText addTxtName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.addTxtName);
                EditText addTxtNumber = dialog.findViewById(R.id.addTxtNumber);
                Button btnAction = dialog.findViewById(R.id.problmBtn);

                btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String name = "", number = "";
                        if (addTxtName.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please add a valid name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else{  name = addTxtName.getText().toString();
                        }
                        if (addTxtNumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please add valid contact number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else { number = addTxtNumber.getText().toString();
                        }
                        list.add(new ContactModel(name, number));
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size() - 1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        initList();



    }

    private void initList() {
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.a, "Kalyan","9875410316"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.b, "Uttam","9083080056"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.c, "Bulu","8583020544"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.d, "Pampa","9999999999"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.a, "Kalyan","9875410316"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.b, "Uttam","9083080056"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.c, "Bulu","8583020544"));
        list.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.d, "Pampa","9999999999"));


        adapter = new ContactRecyclerAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

The layout file for the custom Dialog is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/teal_700">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_new_contact"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/teal_200">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/llRow"
            android:padding="11dp">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addImgContact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/contact_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UselessLeaf"
                android:background="@color/white">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addTxtName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/contact"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_dynamic_primary40"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:autofillHints="name" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addTxtNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/contact_number"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral30"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:autofillHints="phone" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/problmBtn"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_new_contact"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_primary20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely add items to recyclyerview always, as you have not included

```
list.add(new ContactModel(name, number));
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size() - 1);
```

this piece of code inside any condition, you need to check if name and contact is not empty only then this code should run, and also you need to improve your if/else condition for better toast message.

Comment: That block of code I do have in my code as well.

Comment: re read my answer, you have this code but that's not within any condition and that's why it always run weather you have empty fields or not.